# Nginx - php script display as text

Tags: nginx

I created LEMP on my centos VPS

My problem is that when I run php script, part of script displays as text and does not work.

Attached image:

[image]

my nginx config:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    location /phpmyadmin {
        root   /home/sites/example.com/phpmyadmin/phpMyAdmin;
        index   index.html index.htm index.php;
    } 

    location / {
        root   /home/sites/example.com;
        index index.php  index.html index.htm;
    }

    error_page  404              /404.html;
    location = /404.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html { 
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        root           /home/sites/example.com;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }}
```

Comment: Check your PHP files to make sure that they start with `<?php` and do not have a [BOM](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-byte-order-mark.en.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have disabled PHP short_open_tag (

Find your php.ini file

```
php -i | grep php.ini
```

find short_open_tag in that file and set them to On

```
short_open_tag=On
```

Comment: It's better to _don't use short open tags in PHP code_.